# Postgresql and GlassFish - cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, mybatis

I have `postgresql 9.4` and `glassfish 4.1`. Besides I use MyBatis inside EJB. Now I try to make **select** from table and this is what I get:

```
javax.resource.spi.LocalTransactionException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.LocalTransactionImpl.commit(LocalTransactionImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.ConnectorXAResource.commit(ConnectorXAResource.java:124)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy312.getLsist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl$1.dispatch(ConnectionImpl.java:195)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.read(ConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ReaderThreadImpl.doWork(ReaderThreadImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.commit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:811)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.LocalTransactionImpl.commit(LocalTransactionImpl.java:106)
    ... 30 more
```

I even tried the following code:

```
SqlSession session = ConnectionFactory.getSession().openSession(false);//AUTOCOMMIT
        List list=null;
        try{
            session.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
            TempMapper mapper = (TempMapper)session.getMapper(TempMapper.class);
            list=mapper.readAll();
        }  
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TempBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

However the result is the same. When I used gf+mysql+mybatis I changed relaxautocommit but for postgresql driver there is no such attribute. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: in glassfish web console open postgresql pool and at section transactions set enable to Non transactional connections.

Answer (score 1):

in the glassfish management console.
[image]